# What all does ADB backup and how do I restore part of it?

Tags: adb, backup, nexus-5

I am soon going to unlock bootloader and root my Nexus 5, but I didn't wanted to wipe all the data so I thought of using the ADB backup function to restore after rooting is done.

```
adb backup [-f <file>] [-apk|-noapk] [-shared|-noshared] [-all] [-system|nosystem] [<packages...>]
```

So, I made a full backup, with apk, with shared, all.

First of all, what all does this command backup? I suppose everything. Does it include the system, that is, Android files, like the main ROM files including kernel and stuff? Will the ROM get restored after I restore this backup?

Also, after I have rooted the device (which I have still not done), will I be able to restore just the apps, app data and shared storage from the backup? Or should I just backup the apk with shared data backup and that will do it?

Is it possible with a third-party app, root/non-root? (Titanium Backup, maybe?)

I need to know more.

Comment: Similar question: [I want to transfer my android internet app info](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/126595/9109).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

For what ADB backup does, you might wish to see our [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info). Basically, depending on the command line switches used, it backs up apps (`.apk`) and their data. For a full list of options see [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/general/guide-phone-backup-unlock-root-t1420351).

As for the second part of your question, you might wish to see [Is there a way to look inside and modify an adb backup created file?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/23357/16575) Yes, it's possible extracting parts of it, and yes, [Titanium Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) is one of the apps capable of this. Other ways are described in the linked question.

Also worth a look:

- [How do you extract an App's data from a full backup made through “adb backup”?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28481/16575)
- [Partial adb restore](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/24785/16575)
- [Backup and restore Android Settings and Application through ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/23362/16575)

Comment: It's worth noting *some* apk's will not backup via adb. (the intent is to keep people from stealing apps.)

Comment: @RickyBeam is right. Devs can set the `ALLOW_BACKUP` flag to "No"; I've encountered a couple of such apps. Don't know whether "theft protection" is all behind that, as there were also some open-source apps amongst those.

Comment: @RickyBeam PS: If you want to backup those apps as well, on a rooted device with Xposed Framework installed [Backup All Apps](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.pyler.backupallapps) disables that "lock" :)

Comment: Ouch. Another restriction: it doesn't seem to cover SMS/MMS (see: [Backup/Restore SMS/MMS via ADB on a non-rooted device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/114437/16575)).

Comment: For readers: Well for backing up SMS(no MMS backup) we can use app like [Super Backup : SMS & Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idea.backup.smscontacts&hl=en).

Comment: @Lucky In most cases, yes. In some cases, no (see the linked question). Apart from that, using something else than `adb backup` is a different topic :)

Comment: does adb backup save the sqlite databases?

Comment: If the app-in-question permits, yes. Concerning apps, it archives the APK (when run with `-apk`), the app's data directory (`/data/data/<package_name>`) and some more "little pieces".

Comment: `adb backup` is now deprecated, [no longer documented](https://developer.android.com/tools/adb) and may be removed from a future release. Google is gradually stripping the user from ownership over their phone and its data. It's soon Windows.

Comment: @Nilzor too true unfortunately. Starting with Android 12 I've read it only backs up the APK but not the data – except if the application is compiled for debug. Which is pretty stupid. I understand they want to protect our data – but why from us? Backing up to Google's servers will still be permitted (uses the same back-end as `adb backup`: `bmgr`). I just hope no custom ROM will not honor that change…