# adb restore: 'Invalid restore data'

Tags: adb, backup

My Nexus 6 had a hardware fault so I sent it off for RMA. Knowing in advance that it was highly likely the service people would factory reset it during the process of fixing it, I decided to do an adb backup.  My device is not rooted.

I made two backups, I believe using the command `adb backup all -f backup-file.ab -shared -apk`  My device is encrypted, so I set a backup password.

It generated a 1.6gb backup file which sounded about right.

My phone got fixed and I picked it up yesterday, and as expected it had been factory reset. I went to restore it using `adb restore backup-file.ab`

It brings up the restore prompt on my phone and I enter the backup password and it indicates the restore is starting - but then nothing happens.

Logcat says the following:

```
 BackupManagerService: --- Performing full-dataset restore ---
 ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.bindService:1285 com.android.server.backup.BackupManagerService$FullBackupObbConnection.establish:3150 com.android.server.backup.BackupManagerService$PerformAdbRestoreTask.run:5904 java.lang.Thread.run:818 <bottom of call stack    
 BackupManagerService: Invalid restore data; aborting.
 BackupManagerService: Full restore processing complete.
```

I tried playing around with [`abe.jar`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/), but keep getting vague exceptions thrown on the `unpack` or `info` parameters (that's with the Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy files), but it's quite possible I'm doing something wrong.

Obviously since the device has already been factory reset there's no way I can re-run the backup if the archive is bad. Anyone got any suggestions might be going on?

Comment: Pointer: [What all does ADB backup and how do I restore part of it?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/69567/16575)

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error until I realized I was using the wrong password. After entering the correct password, the restore proceeded normally.