# How to provision an Android phone automatically?

Tags: applications, settings

tl;dr: How can I write a **short declarative description** of the state I want my phone to be in, and then **apply it to a phone?**

After a factory reset or hardware change it's always a pain to get my phone back to a usable state. At the same time I don't trust any random third party service to store my settings:

- I don't have fine grained control over what they actually store. They may sell or leak that information without my knowledge or consent.
- They may be incompatible with future hardware/software, and I won't know until I try to restore.
- They may be incompatible with my configuration (try updating Android after rooting your phone, for example).
- They may at any time be shut down.
- I'll bet none of them allow me to retrieve the data in such a way that I can migrate to another service.

Setting up this sort of thing for your own PC requires very little technical skill and a little time - I've already set up a [repository](https://github.com/l0b0/root) to provision my own desktop and laptop. However, I've no idea how to do something similar on Android. I can't see any mention of a Puppet client, and I don't know if it's possible to provision a device in any sensible way without installing a custom kernel or rooting it.

Comment: I think the best you can do is manually using `adb backup`.  http://android.stackexchange.com/q/69567/1465

Comment: @MatthewRead I wouldn't do a full backup (single file) – and even if, I'm not sure that really covers everything. Like the OP, I want to have control and *know* what's in there. On the same road and coming close (but not close enough yet) is what I created [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) for. But AFAIK ADB backups (even if full) miss parts like SMS and some other stuff. If the device is rooted, Xposed, and BackupAllApps module active one gets quite a lot, but not all.