# Backup data in recovery mode of LG

Tags: backup, recovery-mode, data-recovery, lg

In the program `LG PC Suite` I used the option to recover upgrade errors. Now the phone (LG E975) is in `Recovery mode`. There are no options it only shows the following message:

> Using this mode, service center can back up and recover your data.
>   Press and hold the POWER key more than 8 seconds to reboot and
>   continue using phone.

I searched after this software but it seems that only the LG service team has such one. I want to backup the data on my phone but I don't know what the `LG PC Suite` has already done.

How can I backup the data on the phone if I'm in `Recovery mode`?

**EDIT:**
Solved my problem with the LG PC Suite. I don't need the backup option in recovery mode anymore. I tried a few things, but none of them worked.

Comment: Is the device detected by [ADB](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) (i.e. running `adb devices`)?

Comment: Yes it is detected: `* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached
LG-E975-45xxx321        recovery`

Comment: OK, before I make it a full-fledged answer with some more details, could you try running `adb backup -f dummy.ab -noapk com.foobar` (replacing `com.foobar` with the package name of an app you know is installed on the device)? That should backup the apps data. I never tried that from recovery, hence you've got to do that :)

Comment: It doesn't work because the dialog isn't shown on the screen. I get the message `Now unlock your device and confirm the backup operation.`

Comment: Yuck. Was afraid of something like that. OK, next variant: [Backup and restore Android Settings and Application through ADB](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/23362/16575) (I love our tag-wikis: take a look at the [backup tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info), I should have done that earlier ;)

Comment: I tried the `adb pull` command, DroidExplorer (don't find the sdk) and Simple ADB Backup. Nothing of them worked.
Do you have another idea?

Comment: Custom recovery? Then the last thing I can come up with is a Nandroid backup (single items can be extracted from that lateron). Stock recovery? No idea left at all. Sorry.