# What does ADB Back up restore to an android device?

Tags: adb, restore

Does ADB Back Up contain system files? Supposing an un-rooted android device has got an ADB back up and something goes wrong and the device does not boot up, then can the ADB back up be useful?

Comment: Related / duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/131553

Comment: The usefulness in your described case is you could factory-reset the device and restore the backup to get *most* things back. For "why not *all* things", see the linked question (apps can opt-out of this backup, and some data like SMS is not contained).

Answer (score 0):

For what ADB backup does, you might wish to see our [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info). Basically, depending on the command line switches used, it backs up apps (`.apk`) and their data.

As for the second part of your question, you might wish to see [Is there a way to look inside and modify an adb backup created file?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/23357/16575) Yes, it's possible extracting parts of it, and yes, [Titanium Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) is one of the apps capable of this. Other ways are described in the linked question.

Also worth a look:

- [How do you extract an App's data from a full backup made through “adb backup”?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28481/16575)
- [Partial adb restore](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/24785/16575)
- [Backup and restore Android Settings and Application through ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/23362/16575)

Answer taken from [What all does ADB backup and how do I restore part of it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69567/what-all-does-adb-backup-and-how-do-i-restore-part-of-it)