# Does `adb backup` also backs up what is backed up by Android automatic backup (that is stored on Google Drive)?

Tags: backup

I have two backups: one from Android automatic backup, stored in Google Drive; another is what I manually backed up with `adb backup`.

What are the differences between the two? Do I need to restore the one from Drive as well if I reinstall my OS?

[There is a similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/154193/what-does-adb-back-up-restore-to-an-android-device) but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I cannot say definitely, but my guess would be they back up the same stuff (as both use the same backend AFAIK – look out for "backup transport" and "BackupManager"). So at least the same restrictions apply to both (like, honoring whether an app defined `android:allowBackup="false"` to opt out from backups).

Comment: In general I agree with what Izzy wrote. Additional to the general allowBackup setting the developer can explicitly exclude and include files and directories. I remember that Android online backup has changed had changed over the times since it had been introduced with Android 6. Therefore older devices adb backup and online backup may differ especially if the hat a large data set to backup (>25MB).